# Auto expand <select> tag width on behalf of characters length - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to expand `<select>` tag width on behalf of characters length in `<option>` tag.

Currently, I am using this example: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/ShgWt/ but defining the hard coded width on base of character count and it works on all new browsers except less then IE 9.

But I want a better solution by using jquery/javascript with auto width instead of hardcoded width on behalf of character count.

---

Actually I have dynamic drawn  list. But I have a fixed width for all dropdowns initially on a webpage which I want to change on base of character length of  tag on `onchange` behavior

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually I have dynamic drawn `<option>` list. but i have a fixed with for all dropdowns initially. Which i want to change on base of character length of `<option>` tag onchange beahvior

Comment: Yes, i re-read the question and realized that - and deleted my comment. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. This assumes that the div `test` is using the same font as the select box is. Basically I dump the text into a div, measure the div width, and clear the div. Then I assign that width to the select box.

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/ShgWt/5/

**HTML**

```
<!--Add right before </body> tag -->
<div id='test'></div>
```

**JS**

```
function countit(what){
    var formcontent = what.form.charcount.value;
    var t = $('#test');
    t.html(formcontent);
    var w = t.width() + 25;
    t.html('');
    $("#selectBox").css ({'width' : w + "px"});
}
```

**CSS**

```
#test{float:right;}
#selectBox{width:80px;}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.. but still issue in IE7, IE8

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you be able to accomplish this by not specifying any width in the `<select>` at all? If I am correct auto expand is a default behavior of non-specified width selects.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too.  Doesn't `<select>` always want to be as wide as the longest `<option>` within?

Comment: Actually on web page there are many dropdown lists having same width for all (for page styling purpose). And each dropdown list has different options with different character length.